# How to convert an array of data to a list of widgets with expand or fold in flutter/dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, casting, reduce

Really frustrated about not solving it myself but finally gave up.
I have an array of fields, each being a map with title and value. I want to iterate through it and create a list of text widgets along with some padding between them. I tried the following:

```
fields.expand((field)=>
                  [ Text(field['title']), 
                    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0))
                  ]
             ).toList()
```

But this gives the following error:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
```

I tried adding `<Widget>` after `expand` but then I get:

```
type 'MappedListIterable<Map<String, String>, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
```

I also tried adding `<Widget>` after `expand(` but then I get:

```
type '<Widget>(dynamic) => List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type '(Map<String, String>) => Iterable<dynamic>' of 'f'
```

Not sure what else to do. How the heck can I force it to realize this is a list of widgets?
I also tried using fold but got similar typing issues.

Comment: @christopher-moore Indeed I need it as a list of widgets as it’s used as the children of a column. What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the `expand` function. Could you print the result of the `fields.expand.toList()` line?

Comment: The printing of the list seems ok: ```[Text("Some text"), Padding(padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0))]```. But somehow it thinks it is ```List<dynamic>``` and doesn't let it convert to ```List<Widget>```. Any suggestion?

Comment: Seems like your attempt adding `expand<Widget>`, should've worked. I'll post an alternative with `for-each`.

Comment: I'm updating my SDK now. Maybe my version is too old and is causing this...

Comment: What version of the dart SDK were you using?

Comment: Was ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0". Just changed to ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0". I'm now cleaning, upgrading flutter and rebuilding everything...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `.map()`, but there's a cleaner way to do it :

```
items: [
    for(var field in fields)
        ...[
            Text(field['title']), 
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0)),
        ]
]
```

*Make sure your minimum SDK version is 2.6.0 or above in the pubspec.yaml*

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for. ```.map()``` can only turn each element  of the array into a single widget, while here I want to generate two widgets from each (a ```Text``` and a ```Padding```. Your suggestion above also won't work since I want to put all the generated elements into a single column, and not each pair in its own column.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. I edited my answer to use the spread operator, which makes it even simpler (without the Column).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, one of your solutions appears to should have work, but since it didn't I'm providing an alternate solution.

You can use a `for-each` loop to "manually" create an output `List` that you can pass to your `Column` widget. Ex.

```
List<Widget> columnList = List();
for(Map field in fields) {
  columnList.add(Text(field['title']);
  columnList.add(Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @christopher-moore noted, adding `<Widget>` after `expand` does work. The reason I thought it was not working was that I kept getting the error, but for a different place where I still had the same statement but without that addition.